# Inception build_imagenet_data.py TypeError: 'RGB' has type <class 'str'>, but expected one of: (<class 'bytes'>,)

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to use a slight variant of the _convert_to_example() function in [build_imagenet_data.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/data/build_imagenet_data.py):

```
def _convert_to_example(filename, image_buffer, label, bboxes, height, width):

  xmin = []
  ymin = []
  xmax = []
  ymax = []
  for b in bboxes:
    assert len(b) == 4
    # pylint: disable=expression-not-assigned
    [l.append(point) for l, point in zip([xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax], b)]
    # pylint: enable=expression-not-assigned

    colorspace = 'RGB'
    channels = 3
    image_format = 'JPEG'

    example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
      'image/height': _int64_feature(height),
      'image/width': _int64_feature(width),
      'image/colorspace': _bytes_feature(colorspace),
      'image/channels': _int64_feature(channels),
      'image/class/label': _int64_feature(label),
      'image/object/bbox/xmin': _float_feature(xmin),
      'image/object/bbox/xmax': _float_feature(xmax),
      'image/object/bbox/ymin': _float_feature(ymin),
      'image/object/bbox/ymax': _float_feature(ymax),
      'image/object/bbox/label': _int64_feature(label),
      'image/format': _bytes_feature(image_format),
      'image/filename': _bytes_feature(os.path.basename(filename)),
      'image/encoded': _bytes_feature(image_buffer)}))
  return example
```

I get an error associated with the colorspace variable:

> TypeError: 'RGB' has type class 'str', but expected one of: (class 'bytes',)

If I comment out the image/colorspace feature I get the same error for image/format. Likewise for image/filename. If I comment out these three features the function seems to run as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like a Python 2/3 incompatibility issue. You can explicitly create `colorspace` and `image_format` as `bytes` objects by prepending a `b` to the string literals, as follows:

```
colorspace = b'RGB'
# ...
image_format = b'JPEG'
```

Comment: Thanks and confirmed. The problem was noted with py3.4 but is not present using py2.7. Also in addition to your suggestion of prepending b to string literals, the encode() method is useful to apply to string variables.

Answer (score 4):

I noted a few additional changes.

```
o     #shuffled_index = range(len(filenames))
o     shuffled_index = list(range(len(filenames)))
o     #for i in xrange(len(spacing) - 1):
o     for i in range(len(spacing) - 1):
o         'image/class/text': _bytes_feature(text.encode()),
o         'image/filename': _bytes_feature(os.path.basename(filename.encode())),
o     colorspace = 'RGB'.encode()
o     channels = 3
o     image_format = 'JPEG'.encode()
```